# stacked axis in echarts4r R

Tags: r, visualization

How to make stacked plot in echarts4r package?
If I add second y-axis - it's add new series in same plot.

```
data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:5],y=1:5,
               z=6:10)%>%
  e_charts(x)%>%
  e_line(y)%>%
  e_line(z, y.index = 1)
```

[image]

But I'm need some like that:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is you plot on two different Y axis (`y.index = 1`) so you will no be able to stack them, if you plot them on the same Y axis you will be able to stack them.

```
data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:5],
           y=1:5,
           z=6:10
) %>%
  e_charts(x) %>%
  e_line(y, stack = "stack") %>%
  e_line(z, stack = "stack")
```

Note that you do not have to pass "stack" to the `stack` argument, you can pass whatever you want, this enables different groups to be stacked.

```
data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5],
           y=1:5,
           z = 6:10,
           w = rnorm(5, 4, 1),
           e = rnorm(5, 5, 2)
) %>%
  e_charts(x) %>%
  e_bar(y, stack = "stack") %>%
  e_bar(z, stack = "stack") %>%
  e_bar(w , stack = "grp2") %>%
  e_bar(e, stack = "grp2")
```

Reason why this option is not explicitly stated in documentation: [ECharts](http://echarts.baidu.com/) comes with hundreds if not thousands of options, listing them all as arguments would be neigh impossible. All options are, however, available in the package; see the [official documention](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#title)

**EDIT**

You can stack on multiple Y axis but not across them. This works too:

```
data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5],
           y=1:5,
           z = 6:10,
           w = rnorm(5, 4, 1),
           e = rnorm(5, 5, 2)
) %>%
  e_charts(x) %>%
  e_bar(y, stack = "stack") %>% # defaults to y.index = 0
  e_bar(z, stack = "stack") %>% # defaults to y.index = 0
  e_bar(w , stack = "grp2", y.index = 1) %>% # secondary axis + stack
  e_bar(e, stack = "grp2", y.index = 1) # secondary axis + stack
```

For multiple charts as you initially wanted, one x axis, multiple Y axis, 2 plots on one page:

```
df <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:5],y=1:5, z=6:10)

df %>% 
  e_charts(x) %>% 
  e_line(y) %>% 
  e_line(z, y.index = 1, x.index = 1) %>% 
  e_y_axis(gridIndex = 1) %>%
  e_x_axis(gridIndex = 1) %>% 
  e_grid(height = "35%") %>% 
  e_grid(height = "35%", top = "50%") %>% 
  e_datazoom(x.index = c(0, 1)) # brush http://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/brush.html
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! it's example for stacked data, but i'm need for stacked y-axis, where they will be one under one like on second picture.

Comment: unfortunatly not, can't make multiples y-axis

Comment: Stacking across axis is not physically doable, no library will let you do that if you need to stack then, by definition, you not need multiple axis.

Comment: i'm looking for that df=data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:5],y=1:5,
           z=6:10)
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(df,"line",hcaes(x=x,y=y),yAxis = 0)%>%
  hc_add_series(df,"line",hcaes(x=x,y=z),yAxis = 1)%>%
   hc_yAxis_multiples(list(
    top = "0%",
    height = "50%",
    opposite=FALSE),
    list(top = "51%",
      height = "50%",
      opposite=T))

Comment: maybe i've given bad explanation of what i need

Comment: OK, you wanted multiple plots, 1 X axis, multiple Y: see bottom of answer.